# Does anyone know of a good free tool that can be used to ping our Postgres database server to determine if it is running or not?

Tags: monitoring, postgresql

I'm looking for a free tool which runs on my desktop (not the server itself) that will periodically test to see if our database server is up and running properly. Ideally, it should also be able to test if web pages are up as well.

Does anyone know of anything that can do this as pain-free as possible?

Answer (score 1):

There are several Tools which can do what you are looking for, [Nagios](https://www.nagios.org/), [Spiceworks](http://www.spiceworks.com/) are both free, there are several which are Paid. Some are windows, some are linux based.

Spiceworks is probably the easiest of the two to setup but has more limited monitoring ability.

Nagios is harder to configure at the beginning, but can check a lot more.

There are more out there. these are the two that i have the most experience with.
They will all require some configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following:

- [Monitoring Plugins - check_pgsql](https://www.monitoring-plugins.org/doc/man/check_pgsql.html)
- [Monitoring Plugins - check_http](https://www.monitoring-plugins.org/doc/man/check_http.html)